# concern regarding travel - zusatzblatt zum aufenthaltstitel

Tags: germany, blue-card

I am planning to travel to India from Germany next week and return planned after one month.
The concern is my daughter's Blue Card is expired. But she has "Zusatzblatt zum Aufenthaltstitel" and it's content is like below

**front page**

> *Dieses dokument gilt als zusatzblatt zum/ Aufenthalstitle*
>
> *Nr: xxxxx*
>
> *bis zum **20.03.2023***

**back page**

> *Nebenbestimmungen Der Inhaber/Die inhaberin ist im besitz eines aufenthaltstitels bis **30.09.2025**.  Die eintragung des datums unter
> 'Gultig Bis" auf dem kartenkorper des elektronischen
> aufenthaltstittels hat technishe grunde*

Will I have any issues during the travel (from Germany to India and India to Germany)?

Thanks in adavance

Comment: The text states that the residence permit is valid until 30.09.2025 and that the printed date on the card (20.03.2023) is not correct. With the Zusatzblatt there should be no problem.

Comment: @MarkJohnson do you think there will be someone at check-in in India who can read German?

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar situation when I was travelling from Azerbaijan to Germany. Blue card expired in 2023, but Zusatzblatt mentioned "Blaue Karte gültig bis 2025" ("Blue card is valid until 2025").

At the check-in counter they noticed this, I told them to look into Zusatzblatt. They didn't speak German but they believed me. If anyone is in the same situation, I suggest not carrying a checked-in baggage, so that you can online check-in to skip this step. Or buy the flight from the German carrier who can read the Zusatzblatt. Or get a notarized translation to English.

Azeri passport controller was even chiller, asked am I sure my card is still valid. I confidently said yes. He said, you know it better and let me go. So... be confident. Or again, a notarized translation would help you.

German border police just asked me to renew my Blue Card and let me enter Germany.